# SharePoint 2007 Excel Services - Security implications of adding root as a trusted location

Tags: excel-services, 2007

I've done some searching and can't find a definitive answer. In a large SharePoint environment where it'll become a hassle to add individual trusted locations for Excel Workbooks, is adding the root site and trusting all children a viable alternative? What are potential security risks?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you add the children as trusted locations, the permissions of the site still applies for the content. I have used this method before and never experienced any issues.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Lori said, it isn't so much a security thing as it is a way for Administrators to have some control on where the features can be used.  In large installations it might be a good idea to get a little more granular with where certain services are available.